# How to get JWT token from response header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot

I created my first REST API in Spring Boot and used JWT token. When I send a POST request to my API, I get status OK and in the browser network option I can see a header with JWT token like on the picture. [image: jwt token]

But I don't know how to get this token from the Response Headers and save it in for example local storage. I was trying a lot of things, but nothing works.

This is my POST request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    username: 'linda',
    password: 'password'
    })
});
```

Comment: Just to note, it's a standard practice to return Bearer token in the response body and not in the headers. It totally makes sense if you have no control over it (skip the next part of my comment), but if you have control over it, I would refactor your solution to use response body. It would also eliminate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `response.headers`

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'linda',
        password: 'password'
    })
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'))
});
```

Comment: I did it and I have received a header "tree" in console where I can expand the list and view options such as "delete", "append"and something like this, but i don't see token there and still don't know how to extract this token from there.

Comment: Do u mean console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'))? If yes Im getting null in console.

Comment: If you want the front-end to access the Authorization header, your Spring Boot API will have to answer a header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` with the value of `Authorization` so that the Javascript code can access the Authorization header.

Answer (score 3):

There is soultion if someone has the same problem.
You have to add to ur config class this bean:

```
    @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token","Authorization"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```